erratically behavior of TaskScheduler
I have a Vb.net Windows form Application that runs as expected when double clicking on the .exe file, however, when the TaskScheduler tries to execute it, it gets the error 0XE0434352, the weird part is that this happens kind of erratically... it runs every hour. it fails 2-3 times and does one correct execution(checking the logs modification date, this is the only thing I've been able to notice).
I Checked the event viewer and I see the next error:

Description: The process ended due an unhandled exception.
exception information: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
in System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)

By this, I think it's safe to assume the issue is a weird permission/access configuration. but I can not figure out why it sometimes works and sometimes does not.
the code to write in the file is simple, inside a function I do:
If Not Directory.Exists("Logs") Then
    Directory.CreateDirectory("Logs")
End If
Using w As New StreamWriter("Logs\" & File, True)
    w.WriteLine("[" & Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss") & "] " & Text)
End Using

If it is worth, I have other console apps (created in c# .net), those apps also create a log file with the same method, the same "executedBy" user and the same taskscheduler configuration, every task has defined a "start on" path. only the one in vb.net fails which is giving me headaches, anyone know what to look for?
